# Two code sum solution provided in stackoverflow doesnt works even on IntelliJ

Tags: scala

i have tried making the code work  even on intellij still it doesnt shows output ,what more basics are required ,i have used your function using scala 2.13 and put inside Object which extends App

[image: No output shown evenon IntelliJ]

Continuation from [Leet code showing return code compiler problem with Scala code for 2 sum problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803428/leet-code-showing-return-code-compiler-problem-with-scala-code-for-2-sum-problem)

Comment: Well you aren't printing the output of the method, the method is not even called. Try adding this line anywhere inside the object `println(twoSum(ArraySeq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 5))`

Comment: yeah that println was a basic thing which i missed thanks

Comment: So, did it worked now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently with help of above gentleman and using scala function as object was able to execute the function

```
package playground

import scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq

object ScalaPlayground extends App {

 val summer = new MyFunction {

      println(twoSum(ArraySeq(2, 7, 11, 15), 26))

 }


}

  trait MyFunction{



   def twoSum(nums: ArraySeq[Int], target: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
   val allIndexes = for {
    i <- Iterator.range(start = 0, end = nums.length)
    j <- Iterator.range(start = i + 1, end = nums.length)
  } yield i -> j

  allIndexes.find {
    case (i, j) => (nums(i) + nums(j)) == target
      }
   }


 }
```